# Insert } to Complete ClassBody error even with matched braces

Tags: java, android

Yes. I know this is trivial. But this is getting silly.

Image proving the error:

[image]

The code:

```
package apack.age;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class DisplayContactActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.display_contact_layout);
    }

    public void openSubreddit(View view)
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.reddit.com")));
    }

    public void openTwitter(View view)
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://twitter.com")));
    }

    public void openGmail(View view)
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("www.gmail.com")));
    }
}
```

Seriously. There's 5 open and 5 close braces. This is my first attempt at an android app but I have 3 years of Java experience so this is pretty frustrating.

Run errors out. Refresh does nothing. Project clean does nothing. Auto code format in eclipse (CTRL + SHIFT + F) does nothing.

EDIT 1: Copying the code to a new class gets it to compile. I'm running the new version of Eclipse: Juno. I've done source -> cleanup and it just says "nothing to change" every time!

Comment: Have you tried to add a line to the end of the file?

Comment: Just Clean your Project from **Project->Clean..** on Eclipse IDE

Comment: Project clean doesn't work, as posted in the original problem. Says "there's no changes to make".

Adding newline to the end of the file doesn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit: Please upgrade to ADT 20.0.1, where this has been fixed.

---

Switch to the **Lint** view, use the Clean button to remove all lint errors. There is a [bug with lint](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33985) in ADT 20, that it sometimes takes over the Java compiler bugs.

You can verify if this is really the problem by looking at the "Origin" column of this bug in your Problems view. Normally that should be "Java problem" for this error, but it will be "Lint" instead.

Comment: Edit! Found the Lint button, one click and it fixed it right away! Fantastic. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 1):

Try to save the file with `Ctrl+S`, it happens to me sometimes. Also, it seems that you forget  to insert the package name at the beginning of the code:

```
package com.example.my_application;
```

Comment: Clean up says 'there's nothing to change' as I posted on main thread. Package is hidden for privacy purposes. Save is already done.

Comment: Some suggestions: 1- close the eclipse and open it again. 2- If it does not work, create a new class and copy the code into it.

Comment: Alright copying to a new class fixed it. So how to I properly "clean" the old class then?

Comment: @End.Fouad it's not that easy because the class is tied in to other places such as the layout. While it's a decent solution, a cleaner solution to this would be preferred.

Comment: @advocate delete the old class file, and then rename the new one with the old one's name.

Comment: @End.Fouad now that is a much better idea :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's gotta be a snapin in your eclipse with the issue. Have you tried a virgin eclipse install?

Comment: I installed Eclipse for the first time on this machine 6 hours ago =\

Comment: But you also installed the android sdk. Other than the obvious import errors, does the issue go away without the sdk?

Comment: Issue goes away when code is pasted to a new class. Appears to be an Eclipse 'clean up' project error. Problem is clean up isn't changing anything atm.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some tips for Eclipse users who are experiencing this issue. Please try the following, which solved this problem for me (I was using this download of the IDE: eclipse-SDK-4.2-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.tar):

1) mv the offending source .java file to a new file.
2) Refresh eclipse (the project via right-clicking the project name).
3) mv the new file back to the original name.
4) Refresh eclipse again.

This solved the issue for me. It was nothing about the code, it happened for me, intermittently throughout my coding session, even in a very small file in which it was not easy to misplace any closing braces :-)

Answer (score 0):

I tried some of the solutions suggested here, no luck, then tried the below, seems good.

I moved the Java file out of the source tree. Of course, compile errors lit up everywhere else in the tree.

I created a new Java file for the class. I right-clicked on an error to generate the file. I set the parent class in the dialog.

I fixed the errors in the file - constructor required because of parent class - with temporary code.

With the old code open in a text editor (Notepad++), I chunk-by-chunk copy-pasted the old code in, fixing imports as required by right-clicking on the errors.

It compiles happily now.

Grumble. Flaky tools. Grumble.